# Create a Slideshow similar Collectionview

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I created a UICollectionView with custom Cells in a horiztontally swipe diretcion (Image 1).
Now the costumer wants to see the next Cells on the left end the right side of the Display (Image 2).

Has anyone an Idea?[image: ![][1]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks but i already solved this problem using this https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel

Answer (score 0):

You just have to adjust the size of cells. In my case I am showing images as

[image: My image collection]